# CSS Masonry type Image layout responsive

Tags: css

I need to create a responsive Masonry images layout but there are 2 large sections which are going to make it very tricky?

See the attached image:

[image]

How can I get something like that but responsive?

Comment: in masonry it will take care, and the big image will adjust in available area...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to use columns to achieve this.

HTML

```
<section id="photos">
  <img src="images/image-1.jpg" alt="Some Image">
  <img src="images/image-2.jpg" alt="Another Image">
  ...
</section>
```

CSS

```
#photos {
  /* Prevent vertical gaps */
  line-height: 0;
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-gap:   10px;
  -moz-column-count:    3;
  -moz-column-gap:      10px;
  column-count:         3;
  column-gap:           10px;  
}

#photos img {
  /* Just in case there are inline attributes */
  width: 100% !important;
  height: auto !important;
}
```

And some media queries CSS

```
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  #photos {
  -moz-column-count:    2;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  column-count:         2;
 }
}
@media (max-width: 400px) {
  #photos {
  -moz-column-count:    1;
  -webkit-column-count: 1;
  column-count:         1;
 }
}
```

Here is more info in this article [Seamless Responsive Photo Grid](https://css-tricks.com/seamless-responsive-photo-grid/)

Comment: Thank you for the usefull comment.

Comment: This large cell that goes across 2 is my main problem

Comment: Look at the image provided. I need that layout

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a framework like [**Bootstrap**](http://getbootstrap.com/). It's [grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) makes responsive, column-based layouts easy to create.

You'll have to mess around a little bit for [equal heights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695784/how-can-i-make-bootstrap-columns-all-the-same-height) though.

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eynr7h69/1/) with the basic idea (try resizing the viewport to see how it behaves on lower resolutions):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="content">a</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="content">a</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="content">a</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="content">a</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="content">a</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="content">a</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="content">a</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is nothing like my image

Comment: Look at the image provided. I need that layout

Comment: SO does not program your code. SO points you in the right direction.

Comment: I'm not asking anyone to do it all for me. I'm just saying I've got issues with the long one across ... the other stuff I know how to do.